# How to Prevent Embedded Vimeo From Playing Automatically

Tags: php, wordpress, slider, vimeo

I had someone work on a horizontal slider for this wordpress powered site: http://lifebridgecypress.org.  It's setup where the homepage auto-plays the embedded Vimeo video, which only shows as the first slide on the homepage.  For any other page on the site, the video is not displayed, which is what I want.  But I don't know enough to know how to change the code to where the video WILL NOT play automatically when the user gets to the homepage.  **So, I'd like it to be setup where the video WILL NOT play automatically.**

I'd also like to know if there's a cleaner way to setup the code to accomplish the same result.  Here's the code...

```
<?php 
$options = get_option( 'sample_theme_options' );

$slide_1_title = $options['sometext11'];
$slide_1_image = $options['sometext12'];
$slide_1_url = $options['sometext13'];
$slide_1_text = $options['sometextarea1'];

$slide_2_title = $options['sometext21'];
$slide_2_image = $options['sometext22'];
$slide_2_url = $options['sometext23'];
$slide_2_text = $options['sometextarea2'];

$slide_3_title = $options['sometext31'];
$slide_3_image = $options['sometext32'];
$slide_3_url = $options['sometext33'];
$slide_3_text = $options['sometextarea3'];

$slide_4_title = $options['sometext41'];
$slide_4_image = $options['sometext42'];
$slide_4_url = $options['sometext43'];
$slide_4_text = $options['sometextarea4'];

$slide_5_title = $options['sometext51'];
$slide_5_image = $options['sometext52'];
$slide_5_url = $options['sometext53'];
$slide_5_text = $options['sometextarea5'];

$slide_6_title = $options['sometext61'];
$slide_6_image = $options['sometext62'];
$slide_6_url = $options['sometext63'];
$slide_6_text = $options['sometextarea6'];
?>
    <div id="newsSlider"> 
   <div class="lbutton"> 
    <a href="#" class="previous"></a> 
   </div>

<div class="container"> 
<!--<div class="ltrans"></div> -->
<ul class="slides"> 
<?php if (is_home()) { ?><?php if (!empty($slide_1_image)) { ?>
<li>
<div class="left1slider">
<?php if (preg_match ("/\b(?:vimeo)\.com\b/i", $slide_1_image)) { 
// replace
         $video_vim  = $slide_1_image;
         $vimdomain = array("http://vimeo.com/");
         $blank_text   = array("");
         $vim_id = str_replace($vimdomain, $blank_text, $video_vim);
?>
<object width="648" height="356"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=<?php echo $vim_id; ?>&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=00ADEF&amp;fullscreen=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=0" /><embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=<?php echo $vim_id; ?>&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=00ADEF&amp;fullscreen=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="648" height="356"></embed></object>
         <?php } else { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $slide_1_url; ?>" rel="bookmark">
            <img src="<?php echo $slide_1_image; ?>" width="648" height="356" alt="thumb" />
            </a>
         <?php } ?>
         </div>
         <div class="left2slider">
         <h4><?php echo $slide_1_title; ?></h4>
         <p>
         <?php print nl2br($slide_1_text); ?>
            <br>
            <a href="<?php echo $slide_1_url; ?>" class="readmore">GET DIRECTIONS...</a>
        </p>
         </div>
            </li>
            <?php } // END OF SLIDER ?> <?php } // dont show first slider on site except on homepage ?>

            <?php if (!empty($slide_2_image)) { ?>
            <li>
         <div class="left1slider">
         <?php if (preg_match ("/\b(?:vimeo)\.com\b/i", $slide_2_image)) { 
         // replace
         $video_vim  = $slide_2_image;
         $vimdomain = array("http://vimeo.com/");
         $blank_text   = array("");
         $vim_id = str_replace($vimdomain, $blank_text, $video_vim);
         ?>
         <object width="648" height="356"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=<?php echo $vim_id; ?>&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=00ADEF&amp;fullscreen=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=0" /><embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=<?php echo $vim_id; ?>&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=00ADEF&amp;fullscreen=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="648" height="356"></embed></object>
         <?php } else { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $slide_2_url; ?>" rel="bookmark">
            <img src="<?php echo $slide_2_image; ?>" width="648" height="356" alt="thumb" />
            </a>
         <?php } ?>
         </div>
         <div class="left2slider">
         <h4><?php echo $slide_2_title; ?></h4>
         <p>
         <?php print nl2br($slide_2_text); ?>
            <br>
            <a href="<?php echo $slide_2_url; ?>" class="readmore">Read More...</a>
        </p>
         </div>
            </li>
            <?php } // END OF SLIDER ?>

            <?php if (!empty($slide_3_image)) { ?>
            <li>
         <div class="left1slider">
         <?php if (preg_match ("/\b(?:vimeo)\.com\b/i", $slide_3_image)) { 
         // replace
         $video_vim  = $slide_3_image;
         $vimdomain = array("http://vimeo.com/");
         $blank_text   = array("");
         $vim_id = str_replace($vimdomain, $blank_text, $video_vim);
         ?>
         <object width="648" height="356"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=<?php echo $vim_id; ?>&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=00ADEF&amp;fullscreen=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=0" /><embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=<?php echo $vim_id; ?>&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=00ADEF&amp;fullscreen=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="648" height="356"></embed></object>
         <?php } else { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $slide_3_url; ?>" rel="bookmark">
            <img src="<?php echo $slide_3_image; ?>" width="648" height="356" alt="thumb" />
            </a>
         <?php } ?>
         </div>
         <div class="left2slider">
         <h4><?php echo $slide_3_title; ?></h4>
         <p>
         <?php print nl2br($slide_3_text); ?>
            <br>
            <a href="<?php echo $slide_3_url; ?>" class="readmore">More on 50/50...</a>
        </p>
         </div>
            </li>
            <?php } // END OF SLIDER ?>

            <?php if (!empty($slide_4_image)) { ?>
            <li>
         <div class="left1slider">
         <?php if (preg_match ("/\b(?:vimeo)\.com\b/i", $slide_4_image)) { 
         // replace
         $video_vim  = $slide_4_image;
         $vimdomain = array("http://vimeo.com/");
         $blank_text   = array("");
         $vim_id = str_replace($vimdomain, $blank_text, $video_vim);
         ?>
         <object width="648" height="356"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=<?php echo $vim_id; ?>&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=00ADEF&amp;fullscreen=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=0" /><embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=<?php echo $vim_id; ?>&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=00ADEF&amp;fullscreen=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="648" height="356"></embed></object>
         <?php } else { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $slide_4_url; ?>" rel="bookmark">
            <img src="<?php echo $slide_4_image; ?>" width="648" height="356" alt="thumb" />
            </a>
         <?php } ?>
         </div>
         <div class="left2slider">
         <h4><?php echo $slide_4_title; ?></h4>
         <p>
         <?php print nl2br($slide_4_text); ?>
            <br>
            <a href="<?php echo $slide_4_url; ?>" class="readmore">Read More about 72...</a>
        </p>
         </div>
            </li>
            <?php } // END OF SLIDER ?>

            <?php if (!empty($slide_5_image)) { ?>
            <li>
         <div class="left1slider">
         <?php if (preg_match ("/\b(?:vimeo)\.com\b/i", $slide_5_image)) { 
         // replace
         $video_vim  = $slide_5_image;
         $vimdomain = array("http://vimeo.com/");
         $blank_text   = array("");
         $vim_id = str_replace($vimdomain, $blank_text, $video_vim);
         ?>
         <object width="648" height="356"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=<?php echo $vim_id; ?>&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=00ADEF&amp;fullscreen=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=0" /><embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=<?php echo $vim_id; ?>&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=00ADEF&amp;fullscreen=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="648" height="356"></embed></object>
         <?php } else { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $slide_5_url; ?>" rel="bookmark">
            <img src="<?php echo $slide_5_image; ?>" width="648" height="356" alt="thumb" />
            </a>
         <?php } ?>
         </div>
         <div class="left2slider">
         <h4><?php echo $slide_5_title; ?></h4>
         <p>
         <?php print nl2br($slide_5_text); ?>
            <br>
            <a href="<?php echo $slide_5_url; ?>" class="readmore">Read More Details...</a>
        </p>
         </div>
            </li>
            <?php } // END OF SLIDER ?>

            <?php if (!empty($slide_6_image)) { ?>
            <li>
         <div class="left1slider">
         <?php if (preg_match ("/\b(?:vimeo)\.com\b/i", $slide_6_image)) { 
         // replace
         $video_vim  = $slide_6_image;
         $vimdomain = array("http://vimeo.com/");
         $blank_text   = array("");
         $vim_id = str_replace($vimdomain, $blank_text, $video_vim);
         ?>
         <object width="648" height="356"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=<?php echo $vim_id; ?>&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=00ADEF&amp;fullscreen=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=0" /><embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=<?php echo $vim_id; ?>&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=00ADEF&amp;fullscreen=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="648" height="356"></embed></object>
<?php } else { ?>
<a href="<?php echo $slide_6_url; ?>" rel="bookmark"><img src="<?php echo $slide_6_image; ?>" width="648" height="356" alt="thumb" /></a>
<?php } ?></div>
<div class="left2slider">
         <h4><?php echo $slide_6_title; ?></h4>
         <p>
         <?php print nl2br($slide_6_text); ?>
            <br>
            <a href="<?php echo $slide_6_url; ?>" class="readmore">Read More</a>
        </p>
         </div>
            </li>
            <?php } // END OF SLIDER ?>

</ul>
```

**Does anyone know how to do this?  Thanks for your help!**  Oh, and by the way, all of this code is located within the header.php file.

Answer (score 1):

For turning off the autoplay mechanism, I think switching `autoplay=1` to `autoplay=0` will do the trick.

You could do the setup more easily by collecting all the data in an array, and then running a `foreach` loop on every element.

Like

```
$slides = array();
// Repeat as many times as needed to add element to slide
$slides[] = array("title" => "sometext",
                  "image" => "some_other_text",
                  "url" => ....,
                  "text" => .....);
```

and then walk through each element

```
foreach ($slides as $slide)
 {
   echo $slide["title"]; // will contain the title
   echo $slide["image"]; // will contain the image

   etc....

 }
```